# Why won't "sticky" javascript work in Firefox/IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a "sticky" green bar on [this site][1]. As you scroll in Chrome, the bar moves up and sticks to the top of the page and remains fixed as you keep scrolling.  But I just noticed it doesn't do it in Firefox or IE.  The javascript I use is below.  Anyone have any ideas why it's only working in Chrome?  (doesn't work on mobile either, FYI)

```
// to make sub nav stick to top
jQuery(function($) {
    var docked = false;
    var menu = $('.sticky_cta');
    var init = menu.offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function() {       
        if (!docked && (menu.offset().top - $("body").scrollTop() < 50)) {
            menu.css({
                position : "fixed",
                top: 0,
            });
            docked = true;
        } 
        else if (docked && $("body").scrollTop() <= init) {
            menu.css({
                position: "relative",
            });
            docked = false;
        }
    });
});
```

[1]:

Comment: it is flickering when it starts to stick

Comment: First of all, you can use `position:sticky` in Firefox, so Google that. Second, this script is obviously flawed as it doesn't work on anything **but** chrome. I wrote this, so you can use it - http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/Kgcoa

Comment: Opened the link on Chrome and it's not sticking at all. And I get this on the console 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of null - sticky.js'

Comment: Sorry, I was testing something real quick. It's back and should stick on chrome again.  Going to mess with vsync's when i get a chance, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using waypoints to ensure your bar sticks to the top in all browsers, you will find it's very simple to use and also has a shortcut for sticky elements.

Something similar to this should do the trick:

```
menu.waypoint({
    handler: function (direction) {
        if (direction == 'down') {
            menu.css({
                position: "fixed",
                top: 0,
            });
        } else if (direction == 'up') {
            menu.css({
                position: "relative",
            });
        }
    },
    offset: //Whatever offset you need
});
```

Documentation here:

http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

Shortcut:

http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

replace `$("body").scrollTop`  by  `document.documentElement.scrollTop`

`$("body").scrollTop` i think is deprecated, in FF return 0